# CSS background image on the right side of element

Tags: css

I'm creating a horizontal menu and to smooth out the corners on the left and right side of the menu I have a couple of images that I use. The menu itself has a background color.
On the last element I would like to place the `right-image.png` to appear just after the element itself. It works perfectly if I add the image as a new element, but since this really is just an styling issue I would like to leave the markup as it is and only style it using css.
It is probably easy, but I can't get it to work.
This is how the last element should look:
[image]

So basically I'd like to add the image AFTER all elements without using markup. Is this possible?

Comment: Seeing code would certainly help

Comment: Please post both the HTML markup and the relevant CSS rules for it. After 20+ questions asked, one would expect you to know that already.

Comment: Well the reason for not posting it is that its not really adding anything to my question. The html is just an <ul> with <li>'s. And the css only has a background color...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px; height: 50px; /* width and height set as dimensions of image */
    content: url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly after some modification to top and right values :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the :last-child selector
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

Assuming you have an unsorted list for your menu
and your listitems are on "display:inline-block;"

HTML will be

```
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS will be

```
#myMenu {display:block;}
#myMenu li {display:inline-block;}
#mymenu li:last-child {background: transparent url('<your img url here>') scroll 0 0;}
```

test a bit the position of the background since I have no clue how large the image is compared to the last element. For now it's on "0 0"

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help! Im sure this answer is as good as the one i marked correct. Unfortunatly i can only have one correct answer...